# Conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {{% %}}

Tags: ansible

I searched online and tried all examples but in vain. I am getting the following error "Conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {{ % %}}

Appreciate if you could re-write

Contents of hosts.ini

```
[DEVprimaryappservers]
host1.example.com
   
[SITprimaryappservers]
host2.example.com
```

Playbook has

```yaml
- name: add service Service
  include_vars:
    file: inventory/{{ env }}/group_vars/primarystartservices.yml
- name: Start Service
  win_service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: started
  loop: "{{ services }}"
  when: "inventory_hostname in groups[~ env 'primaryappservers']"
```

I had before like below which is when I got conditional statements should not include jinja2 template warning

```yaml
---
- name: sample code
  win_service:
    state: started
  when: "inventory_hostname in group[{{ env }}'primaryappservers']"
```

Comment: I formatted the question but did not fix the last line's `group/groups` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

```
when: inventory_hostname in group[env ~ 'primaryappservers']
```

Conditionals are implicitly Jinja statements, so you do not need to do anything special to access variables.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable if you find the concatenation of the strings confusing. For example,

```yaml
- name: sample code
  win_service:
    state: started
  when: inventory_hostname in groups[my_group]
  vars:
    my_group: "{{ env }}primaryappservers"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_group: "{{ env }}primaryappservers"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} comes from {{ my_group }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups[my_group]
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e env=DEV

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [host2.example.com]
ok: [host1.example.com] => 
  msg: host1.example.com comes from DEVprimaryappservers

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1.example.com: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2.example.com: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```